# SQL query to show previous and present data in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im making a report to display current data and previous data in one row. I have a source table and a current Data table alongside a previous Data table. primary keys for both are the source table row and the specific data for that row. There's 3 situations:

1. where there is the same data in both previous and current.
2. Where it is only in the previous data table.
3. where it is only in the current data table.

What sort of join or joins would i need to have all 3 situations covered and to show null if it does not exist in one or the other. Here's my current query that can only show situations 1 and 3. My code may be a complete mess as I'm only just now getting into using joins. If anything else is needed I will add.

```
select currentData.LineItem,
       currentData.billing_rate,
       prevData.billing_rate,
       currentData.total,
       prevData.pastRate
from (select source.company_name,
             source.LineItem,
             isnull(curr.billing_rate,589.0) as billing_rate,
             curr.total
      from((select d.company_name,f.LineItem
            from dbo.companies as d,
                 dbo.LineItems as f) as source
            full join (select company_name,
                              category,subcategory,
                              LineItem,
                              billing_rate * unitCount as total,
                              isnull(billing_rate,589.0) as billing_rate
                       from dbo.currentData) as curr on source.company_name = curr.company_name
                                                    and source.LineItem = curr.LineItem )) as currentData
     full join (select source.company_name,
                       source.LineItem,
                       isnull(d.billing_rate,589.0) as billing_rate,
                       d.pastRate
                from ((select d.company_name,
                              f.LineItem
                       from dbo.companies as d,
                            dbo.LineItems as f) as source
                     full join (select company_name,
                                       LineItem,
                                       billed_rate * unitCount as pastRate,
                                       isnull(billing_rate,589.0) as billing_rate
                                from dbo.prevData) as d on source.company_name = d.company_name
                                                       and source.LineItem = d.LineItem)) as prevData on currentData.company_name = prevData.company_name
                                                                                                     and currentData.LineItem = prevData.LineItem
                                                                                                     and currentData.billing_rate = prevData.billing_rate
                                                                                                     and ((prevData.pastRate is not null) or (currentData.total is not null))
```

adding a sql script with tables for testing

```
-- ************************************** [dbo].[LineItems]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LineItems]
(
 [lineitem]    varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
 [subcategroy] varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
 [category]    varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_lineitems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([lineitem] ASC)
);
GO
-- ************************************** [dbo].[companies]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[companies]
(
 [company_name] varchar(50) NOT NULL ,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_companies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([company_name] ASC)
);
GO
-- ************************************** [dbo].[prevData]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prevData]
(
 [lineitem]     varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
 [company_name] varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
 [billing_rate] numeric(18,0) NOT NULL ,
 [bill_date]    datetime NOT NULL ,
 [unitCount]    numeric(18,0) NOT NULL ,


 CONSTRAINT [PK_prevdata] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([lineitem] ASC, [company_name] ASC, [billing_rate] ASC, [bill_date] ASC),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_25] FOREIGN KEY ([lineitem])  REFERENCES [dbo].[LineItems]([lineitem]),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_31] FOREIGN KEY ([company_name])  REFERENCES [dbo].[companies]([company_name])
);
GO


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [fkIdx_25] ON [dbo].[prevData] 
 (
  [lineitem] ASC
 )

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [fkIdx_31] ON [dbo].[prevData] 
 (
  [company_name] ASC
 )

GO

-- ************************************** [dbo].[currentData]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[currentData]
(
 [lineitem]     varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
 [company_name] varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
 [billing_rate] numeric(18,0) NOT NULL ,
 [unitCount]    numeric(18,0) NULL ,


 CONSTRAINT [PK_currentdata] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([lineitem] ASC, [company_name] ASC, [billing_rate] ASC),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_22] FOREIGN KEY ([lineitem])  REFERENCES [dbo].[LineItems]([lineitem]),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_28] FOREIGN KEY ([company_name])  REFERENCES [dbo].[companies]([company_name])
);
GO


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [fkIdx_22] ON [dbo].[currentData] 
 (
  [lineitem] ASC
 )

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [fkIdx_28] ON [dbo].[currentData] 
 (
  [company_name] ASC
 )

GO

insert into dbo.companies values ('testcomp1')
insert into dbo.companies values ('testcomp2')
insert into dbo.companies values ('testcomp3')
insert into dbo.lineitems values ('testline','testsub','testcat')
insert into dbo.lineitems values ('testline1','testsub','testcat')
insert into dbo.lineitems values ('testline2','testsub','testcat')
insert into dbo.lineitems values ('testline3','testsub','testcat')
insert into dbo.currentData values ('testline','testcomp1',12,11)
insert into dbo.prevData values ('testline','testcomp1',12,getdate(),11)
insert into dbo.currentData values ('testline1','testcomp1',12,11)
insert into dbo.prevData values ('testline1','testcomp1',12,getdate(),11)
insert into dbo.currentData values ('testline3','testcomp1',12,11)
insert into dbo.prevData values ('testline2','testcomp1',12,getdate(),11)
```

What i want my query to do is display all line items as well as current rate and or previous rate in the same row

Comment: White space and line breaks are wonderful things for making readable Code (and even any langueg, such as English)...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: After formatting that query, it looks considerably overly complicated. It also has a mix of ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 joins, which seems odd.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added the tables and some data as well as what im looking to get

Comment: When using `full join` I expect to see a lot of `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your final selection, it would appear that you need 5 columns:

```
select currentData.LineItem,
       currentData.billing_rate,
       prevData.billing_rate,
       currentData.total,
       prevData.pastRate
from ...
```

Where `currentData.total` is calculated as `currentData.billing_rate * currentData.unitCount` and a similar formula for `prevData.pastRate`.

### Sample data

I have left out the table `companies` as it is not part of your final selection.

```
declare @LineItems table
(
    [lineitem]    varchar(50) not null,
    [subcategory] varchar(50) not null,
    [category]    varchar(50) not null
);

declare @PrevData table
(
    [lineitem]     varchar(50) not null,
    [company_name] varchar(50) not null,
    [billing_rate] numeric(18,0) not null,
    [bill_date]    datetime not null,
    [unitCount]    numeric(18,0) not null
);

declare @CurrentData table
(
    [lineitem]     varchar(50) not null,
    [company_name] varchar(50) not null,
    [billing_rate] numeric(18,0) not null,
    [unitCount]    numeric(18,0) null
);

insert into @lineitems (lineitem, subcategory, category) values
('testline','testsub','testcat'),
('testline1','testsub','testcat'),
('testline2','testsub','testcat'),
('testline3','testsub','testcat');

insert into @currentData (lineitem, company_name, billing_rate, unitCount) values
('testline','testcomp1',12,11),
('testline1','testcomp1',12,11),
('testline3','testcomp1',12,11);

insert into @prevData (lineitem, company_name, billing_rate, bill_date, unitCount) values
('testline','testcomp1',12,getdate(),11),
('testline1','testcomp1',12,getdate(),11),
('testline2','testcomp1',12,getdate(),11);
```

### Solution

You already found the `full join` to preserve all rows from both the first and the second table in the join. With the `coalesce` function you will get the first not `null` value.

```
select  coalesce(cd.lineitem, pd.lineitem) as 'lineitem',
        cd.billing_rate as 'curr_bill_rate',
        pd.billing_rate as 'prev_bill_rate',
        cd.billing_rate * cd.unitCount as 'curr_total',
        pd.billing_rate * pd.unitCount as 'prev_total'
from @CurrentData cd
full join @PrevData pd
    on  pd.lineitem = cd.lineitem
    and pd.company_name = cd.company_name
order by 'lineitem';
```

### Result

```
lineitem   curr_bill_rate  prev_bill_rate  curr_total  prev_total
---------- --------------- --------------- ----------- -----------
testline   12              12              132         132
testline1  12              12              132         132
testline2  NULL            12              NULL        132
testline3  12              NULL            132         NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you need all lineitems for all companies, even if they do not have row in either data tables.

I'm thinking this should do it:

```
        curr.billing_rate * curr.unitCount as total, prev.billing_rate * prev.unitCount as pastRate

from dbo.lineitems as l 
left join dbo.companies as c on 1=1
left join dbo.currentData as curr on curr.lineitem=l.lineitem and curr.company_name=c.company_name
left join dbo.prevdata as prev on prev.lineitem=l.lineitem and prev.company_name=c.company_name
```

The join with companies is on a constant (1=1) so that we have a m*n product (one row for each pair of company_name, lineitem).

If prevData contains multiple lines for each lineitem and company, the left join could be replaced with a outer apply (select top 1 ...) or a subquery.
If the prevData table is large(100k+ lines), perhaps a ranking function.

There's only so much i can say if the question is not very clear.